# Dealing with multi dimensional data

Tags: jquery, database-design, d3.js

Also, posted on d3 forum: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/d3-js/F2vDEiaCGqI

In continuation with my previous post https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/d3-js/rk./d3-js/M288z95iMxA/mDTlSwhCq6UJ

Now I am adding another dimension to my data. Say I am collecting weather data of 100 cities.
I have the parameters of: daily_high, daily_low, precipitation, etc. which show the average for the entire month.
Now, I want to show the daily data whenever I select a particular city. i.e. 2 views, 1 showing the overview of monthly averages and 2nd showing details of selected city. How do I go about creating the data structure for this? Meaning, do i have the total/monthly averages and the daily data in a single file or multiple fies?
Initially I was using a csv with just the monthly averages to form the table.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you use JSON in the following format:

```
{    
    "London" : {
        "January" : {
            "1" : {
                "high": 100,
                "low": 50,
                "precipitation": 300,
            },
            "2" : {
                "high": 100,
                "low": 50,
                "precipitation": 300,
            },
            MORE DAYS OF THE MONTH...
        },
        MORE MONTHS...
    },
    MORE CITIES...
}
```

You can calculate averages dynamically when processing the data, rather than include them in the data.

Comment: What are the overhead/latency issues if I use json for the following dataset :

100 cities
7-8 parameters
365 days

Comment: Have a look at this article - http://lowlatencyweb.wordpress.com/2012/03/22/150000-requestssec-dynamic-html-json-can-be-fast/

Comment: Probably best to use a database and send requests to a URL that queries that database based on the query string, returning JSON

Comment: E.g. look at the Twitter API http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=twitter

Comment: Returns JSON based on a database

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! 
What, according to you, will be the easiest to setup in my case? I ask since I do not have much experience setting up something (url based querying db ) like this.

Comment: If you use PHP, you can retrieve the query string variables using $_GET and then use those variables with an SQL language to query a database, formatting the data returned in a foreach loop into JSON